# Use Promise to get Custom Dialog Result, Simplified Example

Tags: javascript, promise, customdialog

Beginner question here. At various points in my script I need the user to choose something from a selection of radio buttons on a CustomDialog, and then select from a second set of options based on their answer to the first dialog box, and then get that (asynchronous) response back into my main code so I can act on it further.

I can think of some ugly workarounds within my current skill-set, but after a lot of  googling it looks the “right” way to handle this is with promises, so I’m trying to learn how. Eventually two promises will need to be chained, but I’m hoping I can tackle that once I understand the structure of the initial promise. What I have so far is clearly not right…

Many thanks for any and all schooling/advice.

```js
function callRadio(myArray,myTitle){ 
//Call the HTML file and set the width and height
  
  Logger.log('callRadio has been called, with this array: ',myArray);
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Radio_Template')
  
  
      html.myArray = myArray;
       var html = html.evaluate().setHeight(18.5 * myArray.length + 75);
  
  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, myTitle);
 
};

function runsies(value){

    //Receive value from .html back to .gs side. Display the value submitted from the dialog box in the Logger. 
    Logger.log("index of user selection is: ",value);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue(value) 
    return(value);  
    //Fine as far as it goes , but I want to call this asynchronous output back to
    // the test2 function to act on it further.
  
};


function test2(){ //attempt to set up my dialog calls in a promise (and later use .then to chain the follow-up question, but I don't understand the first promise structure yet)

    var myTitle1 = "Select your favorite fruit"; //for testing purposes. Will otherwise be a variable string passed to test2()
    var myArray1 = ["apples","bananas","grapes"]


    var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var theAnswer1 = callRadio(myArray1, myTitle1).successHandler;// This calls the CustomDialog just fine, but is clearly not the right way to get at the returned value  
        Logger.log("What's going on inside the promise?: ",theAnswer1)//Logger returns null
      if (theAnswer1 >=0) { /* if everything turned out fine */
        resolve(theAnswer1);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error("It broke"));
      }
    });
    
    var x = promise1.then(function(result) {
      Logger.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
    }, function(err) {
      Logger.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
    });
    
    Logger.log('Your favorite fruit is: ', myArray1[x]);
    
    //I need to chain a follow-up question, calling the dialog again based off the first answer(i.e.using callRadio(myArray2[x][1],myTitle2)). 
    //I think if I can get the first promise to work, I can extrapolate that to chain the second promise.

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    
    <? for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ 
    ?>
      <div>
      
        <input type="radio" id="<?= myArray[i] ?>" name="selection" value="<?= i ?>">
        <label for=i><?= myArray[i] ?></label><br>
   
      </div>
    
    <? } ?>
  
  <br>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" >
    </div>
  </body>
  
<script>
      function form_data(){
        var value = $("input[name=selection]:checked").val();
             
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().runsies(value);
        
        google.script.host.close();
      };
      
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Would expect `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()` to return Promise to `callRadio()`, and `callRadio()` to return that Promise to `test2()`.
In `test2()` you would write either `callRadio(myArray1, myTitle1).then(theAnswer => {...})` or `let theAnswer = await callRadio(myArray1, myTitle1);`

Comment: Maybe closer? If callRadio ends with ```return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var theAnswer = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, myTitle);
    Logger.log('from within promise, theAnswer is ',theAnswer);//returns null
    if (theAnswer >=0) { /* if everything turned out fine */
        resolve(theAnswer);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error("It broke"));
      }
    });
  ``` then I still get a null value, which is then passed along to the .then statement. But passed to the .then as a resolve instead of a reject.

Comment: If `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()` doesn't return Promise, then it can only be promisified if accepts a callback. 
Giving the synchronously returned `theAnswer` a Promise wrapper won't force `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()` to behave asynchronously.

Comment: So the solution lies, at least in part, in code we can't see ... the internal workings of `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I'm just a beginning learner, and thinking I need to back up a few steps now and get fluent with callbacks before I can wrap my head around Promises. I'm making more headway following online examples of callbacks than I am with Promises.

Comment: Understand. Ansynchronism and promises are a bit mind-blowing at first but are actually fairly simple. You'll get there.